# Why does JodaTime's DateTime class have a minusMillis() method?

Tags: java, jodatime

Just idly wondering really, the DateTime class in the awesome JodaTime library has a

`minus(long millis)`

method, which returns a new DateTime object minus the specified number of milliseconds, so why would I ever need the

`minusMillis(int millis)`

method, which does the same but with an Integer number of milliseconds?  `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in milliseconds is only 24 days, which isn't that helpful, and presumably it just converts the `int` to a `long` and pumps it into the other method anyway?

The JodaTime library is so well written that I figure there's probably a reason that I'm missing.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minusMillis(int)

EDIT: To clarify, I'm wondering why I should use the `minusMillis(int)` method - I understand what the more powerful `minus(long)` method is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect its because in version 1.0 there way only the `minus(long duration)` method but in version 1.1 there was `minusXxxx(int units)` added resulting in `minusMillis(int)` being add for consistency and `minus(long)` was not removed for back-ward compatibility.

BTW: there is a `plus(long duration)` and a `plusMillis(int millis)` for, I imagine, the same reasons.

Comment: Surely minus(long) isn't legacy, it's a much more powerful method - you can subtract effectively arbitrary lengths of time with it, rather than just ~24 days.  I thought it might just be for consistency, but as I mentioned, with a library this well thought-out I wondered if there was a more concrete reason.

Comment: I agree its worth keeping, so if you are going to add `minuxXxxx(int)` methods later you end up with two methods which do very similar things. If the library were redesigned now, you might combine them into one method.

Comment: OK, so I guess it is just for consistency.  I'll accept this answer for that reason.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The method minusMillis(int millis), can subtract maximum Integer.Max milliseconds which when converted to days is (2^31 -1) is roughly 24.8 days

so if you want to subtract two date objects such that date1 -(no. of days) where no.of days is > 29, then you cannot do it using minusMillis(int millis), therefore the method

[DateTime minus(long duration)](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minus%28long%29)

is provided.

Comment: Yeah sure, I was wondering why you'd ever use minusMillis() when minus() is better (and shorter!)

Answer (score 1):

Then you look into the source of `DateTime` you will find out that both methods eventually call [`DateTime.withMillis(long newMillis)`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withMillis%28long%29). `DateTime.minus(long duration)` calls `DateTime.withDurationAdded(long durationToAdd, int scalar)` which basically does nothing than convert the milliseconds into the desired format for `DateTime.withMillis(long newMillis)`.

So i assume that `minus(long duration)` exists just for compatibility reasons.

Comment: It's interesting that they both end up doing the same thing, but it makes me wonder even more why they bothered adding the minusMillis() method!

Comment: @Conan: This might be just a design decision. Having `minus{Hours,Days,Minutes,...}` but no `minusMillis` could cause irritations.